# VB.NET -> SQL Exporting String "901-0656" to not be 245 (901 minus 656)

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am trying to add new records to a Access database through VB.NET.  The table "Quantities" has three columns:

> PartNumber (string), PadsPerStrip (integer), and Verified (boolean)

The format that we use for PartNumber is ###-####-### (ie 901-0656-000).  When I run my code everything is added correctly but math is performed on Part number so that the - is treated as a minus sign even though it is a string.  Here is my sql command:

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Quantities (PartNumber, PadsPerStrip, Verified) VALUES ( " & partNum & ", " & updatingPPS.ToString() & ", No);"
```

When viewing the command in a MsgBox it shows up as:

```
INSERT INTO Quantities (PartNumber, PadsPerStrip, Verified) VALUES (901-0656-000, 3, No);
```

Is there a way to make it skip the math operator when exporting the part number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enclose the part number with quotes. Without that, the value is not considered as a string when run in the database.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Santos, new command text is:

    cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Quantities (PartNumber, PadsPerStrip, Verified) VALUES ('" & partNum & "', " & updatingPPS.ToString() & ", No);"